# Pass Chart Mouse events to formatted labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I have created a chart using Highcharts, with customized labels to explain about the details of the chart.

now, if i hover on any project(ex; bar chart, column chart) the respective customized label should be highlighted or get selected.

below is the code for my chart,

```
$(function () {
        $('#ao-projectssummry-chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: "columnrange",
                inverted : true
            },
            title: { text: null },
            credits: { enabled: false },
            legend: { enabled: false },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b',
                            new Date(this.x))  ;
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                opposite: true,
                title : null,
                crosshair: {
                    width: 2,
                    color: "#F26C6D",
                    snap: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%a - %a - %y', new Date(this.x));
                    }
                },
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridZIndex: 0,
                type: 'datetime',
                min: Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1),
                max: Date.UTC(2016, 11, 31),
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Set up', 'Quantification of Benefit', 'Execute', 'Deploy to Pilot Stores', 'Full Deployment', 'Roll out to Production'],
                min: 0,
                max: 5,
                title: null,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridZIndex: 0,
                labels:
                    {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                crosshair: {
                    snap: true

                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointWidth: 10,
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    marker: {
                        enbled : false
                    }

                },
                line: {
                    lineWidth:-1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius:0,
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    }

                }
            },
            series: [

                {
                name: "Project Tire Sale",
                data: [
                  {
                      x: 0.40,
                      low: Date.UTC(2016,0,15),
                      high: Date.UTC(2016,2,15),
                      color: "#60B3D1"
                  },
                  {
                      x: 0.40,
                      low: Date.UTC(2016,2,15),
                      high: Date.UTC(2016,4,24),
                      color: "#60B3D1"
                  },
                  {
                      x: 0.40,
                      low: Date.UTC(2016,4,7),
                      high: Date.UTC(2016,6,15),
                      color: "#9CCB01"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                      x: 0.40,
                      low: Date.UTC(2016, 6, 7),
                      high: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 15),
                      color: "#9CCB01"
                  },
                  {
                      x: 0.40,
                      low: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 7),
                      high: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                      color: "#9CCB01"
                  }
                ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Project Tire Sale',
                    type: 'line',
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: 0.40,
                            y: Date.UTC(2016,2,15),
                            marker: {                        
                                symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/ao-calendar.png)',

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            x: 0.40,
                            y: Date.UTC(2016,4,10),
                            marker: { 
                                symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/ao-graph.png)',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            x: 0.40,
                            y: Date.UTC(2016,6,15),
                            marker: { 
                                symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/ao-runningman.png)',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            x: 0.40,
                            y: Date.UTC(2016, 8, 5),
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/ao-a.png)',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            x: 0.40,
                            y: Date.UTC(2016, 10, 15),
                            marker: {
                                symbol: 'url(/../Content/Img/ao-green-arrow.png)',
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
           ]
        });
    });
```

below is the expected output: 
[image]

as shown in the image if we click/hover on the chart the grey background should be shown.

Please help. thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have live example of your code with your custom labels? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: you can refer this jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/0jpovpzr/

Comment: You can make custom crosshair, make longer gridLines and change class of your label to selected (for example using jQuery). Here you can see an example: http://jsfiddle.net/0jpovpzr/2/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński its just awesome and thanks a lot! and i forgot add something that Hovering/clicking event is vice versa. if we click on label also, the chart should get selected. is that possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/0jpovpzr/4/

Comment: Exactly what i needed, great!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have added it as an answer to your topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom crosshair using renderer.rect() method, You can get coordinates of your point using click or mouseover events callback functions. You can use jQuery for adding new class to your labels, and format your labels another way inside css. You can also make your gridLines a little bit longer using jQuery.

Here you can find function for making your gridLines longer:

```
var longerGridLines = function(chart) {
  var d;
  Highcharts.each($('.highcharts-grid')[0].children, function(p, i) {
    d = p.attributes.d.value
    d = d.substring(d.indexOf(' ') + 1, d.length - 1);
    d = d.substring(d.indexOf(' ') + 1, d.length - 1);
    p.attributes.d.value = 'M 0 ' + d;
  })
},
```

Here you can find an example of mouseOver event function:

```
mouseOver: function() {
  $('.cross').remove();
  Highcharts.each($('.customLabel'), function(p, i) {
    $(p).removeClass('customLabelSelected');
  })
  $($('.customLabel')[this.x]).addClass('customLabelSelected')
  var xAxis = this.series.xAxis,
      distance = xAxis.toPixels(1) - xAxis.toPixels(0),
      plotTop = xAxis.toPixels(this.x - 0.5),
      width = this.series.chart.chartWidth;
  this.series.chart.renderer.rect(0, plotTop, width, distance)
  .attr({
        fill: 'rgba(200,200,200,0.5)',
        zIndex: 1
   }).addClass('cross')
   .add();
},
```

And here you can find simple example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/0jpovpzr/5/

Best regards,

Comment: with pagination it giving this following error "<path> attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "M 0 70.5 L 1100 " :(

Comment: Could you please post live example showing this issue?